# R Shiny: Why doesn't ggplot work?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to make a plot using ggplot2 for the following data:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuVlA.png)

```
Name       date   weight   height 
Cat1 2016-03-01 34.20000 22.50000
Cat1 2016-04-01 35.02080 23.01750
Cat1 2016-05-01 35.86130 23.54690
Cat1 2016-06-01 36.72197 24.08848
Cat2 2016-03-01 33.55000 22.96000
Cat2 2016-04-01 33.61710 23.41920
Cat2 2016-05-01 33.68433 23.88758
Cat2 2016-06-01 33.75170 24.36534
```

The code I'm using:

```
library("shiny")
library("xlsx")
library("ggplot2")

animal <- read.xlsx("C:\\data\\animals.xlsx",1)

ui<- fluidPage(
 titlePanel("Animals"),
 sidebarLayout(
 sidebarPanel(
  helpText("Create graph of height or weight animals"),

  selectInput("anim", 
              label = "Choose an animal",
              choices = c("Cat1", "Cat2"),
              selected = "Cat1"),

  selectInput("opti", 
              label = "Option",
              choices = c("weight", "height"),
              selected = "weight")
  ),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("graph"))
))

server <- function(input, output){
   output$graph <- renderPlot({
   p2 <- ggplot(subset(animal, Name %in% input$anim)) + geom_line(aes(x=date, y = input$opti)) 
  print(p2)
})
}
 shinyApp(ui=ui, server= server)
```

I don't get an error, but the output of the plot is just a straight line ([plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvnuq.png)). I don't understand why, if I put the code in the command window with `ggplot`, it does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your *y* aesthetic is a user-provided input rather than a hard-coded R identifier, you need to use `aes_string` instead of `aes`:

```
p2 = ggplot(subset(animal, Name %in% input$anim)) +
    geom_line(aes_string(x = 'date', y = input$opti))
```

Note that you now need quotes around the *x* aesthetic.

Side-note: you can `print` ggplots, but I always find that weird: what does printing a plot mean?<sup>1</sup> `plot` it instead:

```
plot(p2)
```

It does the same, it just looks more logical.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> For the record, I know why ggplot2 provides a `print` function. It’s a neat trick. It just doesn’t make sense to call it explicitly.</sub>

Comment: @jdharrison Nah, they are identical: `identical(ggplot2:::plot.ggplot, ggplot2:::print.ggplot)` → `TRUE`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, the code still doesn't seem to work. I now only get an empty plot without a line.

Comment: I think it needs to be aes_string? So try exactly the same but change 'aes_' to 'aes_string'

Comment: @Pete900 Yes, you’re right. It’s a bit annoying that the rules here are different from the convention in dplyr and other packages.

Comment: Yes! aes_string works perfectly! Thank you so much, I already tried for hours to find what was wrong, but I never thought it had something to do with aes/aes_string. You saved me from so many extra hours of frustration!