# Shiny R. boxplot with selected columns from uploaded file (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I want to add boxplot function to my shiny application but it doesen't want to work well.

This is part of application responsive for file upload

```
  data <- reactive({
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    dataSet <- read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, dec = input$dec )

    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "choices1", choices = colnames(dataSet))


    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox1", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox2", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox3", choices = colnames(dataSet))
    updateSelectInput(session, "combobox4", choices = colnames(dataSet))
        updateSelectInput(session, "combobox5", choices = colnames(dataSet))
            updateSelectInput(session, "combobox6", choices = colnames(dataSet))


    dataSet
  })
```

Of course it sets also column names for some widgets. I use combobox5 and combobox6 to select variables for boxplot in ggplot2.

And of course there is code responsive for making boxplot

```
    output$pudla <- renderPlot({
dat <- data()


ggplot(dat, aes(x=input$combobox5, y=input$combobox6, fill=input$combobox5)) + geom_boxplot()

 })
```

After uploading file, setting right separators etc. and of course by selecting grouping variable and variable to plot via widgets. 
[Only this appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NeW0.png)

And i dont know why box doesen't want to plot.

Comment: You are giving variable names as strings - have you tried using `aes_string` instead of `aes`?

Comment: It worked. Thanks for help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R Shiny: Why doesn't ggplot work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848897/r-shiny-why-doesnt-ggplot-work)